# How to hide UISearchController in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a navigation bar which is displayed without a search bar on it when the screen first displayed. I trigger and display the search bar in Navigation bar but I am wondering how to hide the search bar back and display Navigation bar title again.

I create the search bar as following:

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
//self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.sharedNavigationItem.titleView = _searchController.searchBar;

self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

I want to hide search bar only here and display a normal navigation bar with a title:

[image]

Comment: did u try changing self.sharedNavigationItem.titleView again?

Comment: Did you find a solution, i'm having the same problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide entire navigation bar and if you want to use your own navigation bar, you can first hide navigation controller's navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
//OR
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

or if you have used custom title view for navigation bar, you can do

```
self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;
```

or if you want to hide back bar button item, you can do

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

or if you want to only hide title you can do

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"";
```

And

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = nil ;
```

Comment: None, I want to hide only search bar and display normal navigation bar.

Comment: In your code you added search bar in `titleView`  then try to hide using `self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;` and then `self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = nil ;`

Comment: it did not help.

Comment: it hide search bar or not

Comment: It did not effect anything.

Comment: self.sharedNavigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES; and then self.sharedNavigationItem.navigationItem.titleView = nil ; solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Previous answers suggest to scrap the whole `NavigationBar`, but it is not the researched behaviour. The solution is to add the `searchBar` when the search button is pressed...

```
@IBAction func didPressAddButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // For iOS 11 and later, place the search bar in the navigation bar.
        navigationItem.searchController = tagSearchController 
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    } else {
        // For iOS 10 and earlier, place the search controller's search bar in the table view's header.
        tableView.tableHeaderView = tagSearchController.searchBar
    }

    tagSearchController.isActive = true 
}
```

...and remove it when `didDismissSearchController` is called (`UISearchControllerDelegate` method).

```
func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // For iOS 11 and later, place the search bar in the navigation bar.
        navigationItem.searchController = nil

    } else {
        // For iOS 10 and earlier, place the search controller's search bar in the table view's header.
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    }
}
```

NB: my `searchController` is created and configured in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding below the property.

hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation.

For ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529945/3799720

Another ref:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

[UISearchDisplayController hiding navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538535/uisearchdisplaycontroller-hiding-navigation-bar)

Note: Not tested

Comment: This hides entire navigation bar. I only want to hide search bar and display normal navigation bar.